# Spring boot: Receive LocalDateTime or Instant parameter into my endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to receive a `LocalDateTime` or an `Instant` into my endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(
    path = Constants.AUDITS_MAPPING,
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public Collection<Audit> listPendingAudits(Instant /*or LocalDateTime*/ deadline);
```

Is it possible? Is there any workaround?

Comment: First question is , how do you expect this value from clients , as `String`  or something else ?

Comment: Take date input  as String , this way there are Plenty of options to create datetime object with any format you want.

Comment: Could you provide any answer with minimal helping code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@RequestParam` annotation and send the date value as a query param. For instance:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/resource?date=2018-10-31T01:30:00.000
```

To enable handling of this in Spring you have to add `@DateTimeFormat` annotation to your param:

```
@RequestMapping(
    path = Constants.AUDITS_MAPPING,
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public Collection<Audit> listPendingAudits(@RequestParam(value = "date", required = false)
                                           @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime deadline);
```